# SQL: Error in syntax near 'END' for no clear reason

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create a procedure in phpmyAdmin:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE GetPriceByItemClass(IN itemclass VARCHAR(255))
  BEGIN
    SELECT price FROM hsitems
    WHERE itemClass = itemclass
  END //
DELIMITER ;
```

However, an error keeps coming up saying that I am using incorrect syntax near 'END' at line 5. I don't understand what is wrong as my code seems to be correct.

Comment: Put a semicolon `;` after your SELECT query, before the `END`.

Comment: Yep, I just figured that out. I'm an idiot.